# Crop a CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer with the camera overlay to a UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, avfoundation, overlay

I'm currently looking how I could crop an image with the rectangle from an overlay I have drawn on top of `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`.

The way I draw the overlay is as follows:
ViewController view

- `videoOutputContainer` (UIView)

  - `previewLayer` (AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer)

    - `overlayLayer` (CAShapeLayer)
- other UI elements

The `overlayLayer` is a `CAShapeLayer` in which I cut a hole via this method

```
let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: viewWidth, height: viewHeight)
let cutOutRect = calculateFrameForCardOverlay(width: viewWidth, height: viewHeight)
        
let path = UIBezierPath(rect: rect)
let cutoutPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: cutOutRect, cornerRadius: 16)
        
path.append(cutoutPath)
path.usesEvenOddFillRule = true
        
overlayLayer = CAShapeLayer()
overlayLayer.path = path.cgPath
overlayLayer.fillRule = .evenOdd
overlayLayer.fillColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
overlayLayer.opacity = 0.3
previewLayer.addSublayer(overlayLayer)
```

So the goal is now, when a user takes a picture, I only get the image data from within the cutout.

I have already tried to recreate the cutout with the same ratios as the one on the preview layer, but this does not give the correct results.

To give you an idea of how the screen looks

[image: Overlay]